# Problem with an inner query with SQL using the IN operator

Tags: sql, operator-keyword, in-subquery, khan-academy

So I'm learning SQL at Khan Academy and I can't get my code to work properly to complete the third step of the Playlist maker challenge. I'm supposed to use a nested subquery with an IN operator. I pasted my code below.

The first two sql statements are valid for the steps 1 and 2 of the challenge. The third and fourth statements are my attempts at completing the third step. How do I correct it to complete the challenge?

1. SELECT title FROM songs WHERE artist = "Queen";
2. SELECT name FROM artists WHERE genre = 'Pop';
3. SELECT name FROM artists WHERE genre IN (
   SELECT title FROM songs WHERE artist = 'Queen');
4. SELECT title FROM songs WHERE artist IN (
   SELECT name FROM artists WHERE artist LIKE 'Pop');

Comment: so what is the requirement? Your question should contain everything needed.

Comment: In `3.` you are attempting to filter a genre column against song titles ... the data probably doesn't match up for that. Similarly, in `4.` your subquery filters on artist, when it probably ought to filter there by genre.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing a little bit, because you don't provide schema data here, but `3.` should *probably* be:

```
Select name from artists where genre in (select genre from songs where artist = 'Queen')
```

Which would return all artists that also have a song in any genre where Queen wrote a song.  Similarly, for `4.`:

```
Select title from songs where artist in (select name from artists where genre like 'Pop%')
```

Ought to give you all song titles for all artists if their genre starts with 'Pop'.

Comment: There's an artist table: artists (name, country, genre) and a songs table: (artist, title)

Comment: By the way, your solution for 3 was correct. Thank you